# convective-conductive-radiative heat transfer in human skin

Tags: thermodynamics

Is convective heat transfer basically conductive heat transfer at the border of the materials? Is it a more effective mode of heat transfer in human skin than radiation?

Answer (score 0):

Mechanistically, convective heat transfer is essentially flow enhanced conductive heat transfer, primarily at a boundary.  The fluid velocity field kinematically causes the temperature gradients within the fluid near the wall to increase, and this enhances the rate of conductive heat transfer.  It is definitely a more effective mode of heat transfer in human skin than radiation.  Evaporative mass transfer (diffusive flux) is also increased convectively, and this too is an important cooling mechanism.